# cannot import name SIGNATURE_HMAC

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, importerror, hmac

I am running the [django example](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/tree/master/examples/django_example) provided with [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/), and am getting the following 500 server error.

```
ImportError at /login/bitbucket/
cannot import name SIGNATURE_HMAC
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/login/bitbucket/
Django Version: 1.4.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name SIGNATURE_HMAC
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/core.py in  <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

I searched around in Google and StackOverflow and couldnt find any answers. I have just cloned it and havent changed any code. I have both hashlib and hmac libraries installed

[EDIT]
I upgraded both oauthlib and requests_oauthlib and the error got replaced by a new one

```
AttributeError at /login/bitbucket/
'Request' object has no attribute 'body'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/login/bitbucket/
Django Version: 1.4.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Request' object has no attribute 'body'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/core.py in         __call__, line 46
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Comment: The error occurs in `requests_oauthlib`; make sure that package is up-to-date, including its requirement `oauthlib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, I solved the issue in the title (came from Google) by reinstalling the oauthlib package via pip.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade oauthlib
```

Due to this problem I wasn't able to open Ubuntu Software Center, after upgrading oauthlib everything works normally.